# Error Installing Pandas: ImportError: No module named 'urllib3'

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, conda, urllib3

I have Python 2.7 and anaconda on my mac though I think some of the files related to these programs may have been deleted.  I'm trying to download pandas but I keep getting a long error message that ends in "ImportError: No module named 'urllib3'".

When I run these:

```
conda update conda
conda update anaconda
```

I get the urllib3 error. I've run:

```
sudo pip install urllib3 --upgrade
```

which results in:

The directory '/Users/erinwolpert/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.  The directory '/Users/erinwolpert/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag. **Requirement already up-to-date: urllib3 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages**"

I don't understand why, if urllib3 is up to date, anaconda keeps saying that I don't have urllib3.

Comment: safer solution: just reinstall everything dude: get the anaconda installer again and you're done

Comment: Please paste the full "long" error message. That should lend some insight into what's happening/what needs urllib3.